# Let $(2x − y)^4 = gx^4 + hx^3y + ix^2y^2 + jxy^3 + ky^4$ , where $g, h, i, j, k$ are integers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Let $(2x − y)^4 = gx^4 + hx^3y + ix^2y^2 + jxy^3 + ky^4$ , where $g, h, i, j, k$ are integers.

What is $h$? = $-32$

What is $j$? = $-8$

i'm using the pascal triangle and know that i should start with $4$, but dont know how to proceed?

Comment: btw the answer is -32 and -8 according to me teachers note, but how? i dont know

Answer (score 1):

Look at row $4$ in Pascal's triangle, and you see $1\ 4\ 6\ 4\ 1$. Each number is a coefficient in the expansion of $(A+B)^4$. In other words,

$$(A+B)^4=1A^4+4A^3B+6A^2B^2+4AB^3+1B^4$$

In your case, $A=2x$ and $B=-y$. So $h$, the coefficient of $x^3y$ in your polynomial, comes from

$$4A^3B=4(2x)^3(-y)=4\cdot 8x^3\cdot -y=-32x^3y$$

So $h=-32$.

To get $j$ just do the same thing to the term $4AB^3$.

$$4AB^3=4(2x)(-y)^3=4\cdot 2x\cdot-y^3=-8xy^3$$

So $j=-8$.

Could you do all the other coefficients?

Comment: I got everything beside when you search for h you say 4(2x)^3 (-y) = 4* 8x^3
Where does the 4 come from? Didnt you just use that to multiple into the parentheses?

Comment: @ABCCode: No, the $4$ came from Pascal's triangle, while the $8$ and $x^3$ came from $(2x)^3$. I.e. the eight is two cubed.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If you want werify your correct use of the Pascal's triangle, it is not so hard, in this case, to verify the identites:
$$
(2x-y)^4=(2x-y)^2(2x-y)^2=(4x^2+y^2-4y)^2
$$